# Restore root login via 'sudo mariadb' command

Tags: mysql, mariadb

After `mysql_secure_installation`, `sudo mariadb` command does not seem to work anymore with the following error:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Does anyone know how to restore the login via `sudo mariadb` command?

###### Version Info

- MariaDB: 10.3.32
- Ubuntu: 20.04.1

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I needed to switch from password-based authentication to unix-socket authentication.

I ran this command to change the authentication method for my root user.

```
alter user 'root'@'localhost' identified via unix_socket;
```

References:

- https://mariadb.com/kb/en/authentication-from-mariadb-104/